# How to get array from string

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a string of some data. `string[0]` prints `[31, 37, 3] : [0.12704417954091404]` . I want to get the first array which is `[31, 37, 3]`

Comment: Do you want to get it as a string or as an array of integers?

Comment: anything. but I am expecting array.

Comment: Could you run the command type(string[0]) and tell us the result?

Comment: i think `string` is not type string in your case....

Comment: @compie It's `<class 'inspyred.ec.ec.Individual'>` type. I don't know what it is.

Comment: http://pythonhosted.org//inspyred/reference.html?highlight=individual#inspyred.ec.Individual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a 3rd-party Python library, [`inspyred`](http://inspyred.github.io/) is an AI package for Python.

You appear to have a sequence of [`Individual` instances](http://inspyred.github.io/reference.html?highlight=individual#inspyred.ec.Individual); you'd look up the documentation and see what attributes such instances have. You are looking at the string representation of these instances, but you should be able to access various aspects directly.

The documentation states there are `candidate`, `fitness`, `birthdate` and `maximize` attributes; try these to see which one represents the list you seek.

A quick peek at the [source code](https://github.com/inspyred/inspyred/blob/master/inspyred/ec/ec.py#L175) suggests you want the `candidate` attribute:

```
print string[0].candidate
```

When dealing with new objects in Python, you can always introspect them by using tools such as the `type()`, `dir()` and `vars()` functions, which tell you about the type of object you have, the methods the class defines, and the attributes the instance has.